# Application of Fubini Theorem in Quantum Mechanics

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, quantum-mechanics

I'm afraid I'm very confused by how to correctly apply the Fubini theorem to simplify integrals?

I have some integral

$$
\sum_{k = 0}^{2}\int_{0}^{T} dt_2 \int_{0}^{t_1} dt_1 \bigg[ \big(\psi_{0}(t_2) , V(t_2)\psi_{k}(t_2)\big) \hspace{3 mm} \big(\psi_k(t_1),V(t_1)\psi_0 (t_1)\big)\bigg] \hspace{15 mm} (i)
$$

Where $ (f,\hat{O}g) = \overline{f} \cdot \hat{O}g $ where $f,g$ are some vectors with coefficients in $\mathbb{C}$ and $\hat{O}$ and operator.

So similar to a Euclidean dot product but with the first vector conjugated.

Now the problem I'm having is with applying Fubini's theorem. Below is my derivation

$$
\sum_{k = 0}^{ 2}\int_{0}^{T} dt_2 \int_{0}^{t_1} dt_1 \bigg[ \big(\psi_{0}(t_2) , V(t_2)\psi_{k}(t_2)\big) \hspace{3 mm} \big(\psi_k(t_1),V(t_1)\psi_0 (t_1)\big)\bigg] \\= 
\sum_{k = 0}^{ 2}\int_{0}^{T} dt_2   \big(\psi_{0}(t_2) , V(t_2)\psi_{k}(t_2)\big) \hspace{3 mm}\int_{0}^{T}dt_1 \big(\psi_k(t_1),V(t_1)\psi_0 (t_1)\big)
$$
$$
= \sum_{k=0}^{2} \bigg| \int_{0}^{T} ( \psi_0(t) , V(t) \psi_k(t)) \ dt \bigg|^2  \hspace{15 mm} (\star)
$$

Sorry if that's a mess, I suppose I'm really just curious as to how to get from $(i)$ to $(\star)$ as I'm quite sure the last line is correct.

Thank You.

Comment: This question can be completely ignored, the derivation doesn't follow from here. It follows a completely different path.

Answer (score 0):

Fubini just tells you that you can interchange things: $$f\in\mathcal{L}:\quad\int_{\Omega\times\Omega'} f(x,x')\mathrm{d}x\otimes x'=\int_\Omega\left(\int_{\Omega'}f(x,x')\mathrm{d}x\right)\mathrm{d}x'$$
So what you have to check in order to freely interchange the order of integration is integrability:
$$f\in\mathcal{L}:\iff\int_{\Omega\times\Omega'}|f(x,x')|\mathrm{d}x\otimes x'$$
In your case take the absolute value of the expression in the integral apply Cauchy-Schwarz to split these nasty inner products and see wether the remaining thing is integrable.

*(Let me know when you reach that step.)*